# NDP entries on linux

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

Just as we have /proc/net/arp holding ARP entries in Linux, what is the file that holds the Neighbor Discovery Protocol (NDP) entries? I searched for it on the Linux box running IPv6, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

`ip -6 neighbour` allows you to list and manipulate the NDP table. I can't find a `/proc/` or `/sys/` file containing the information.

Comment: This is the exact location /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all