# what's IPv6 analogue for IPv4 `arp -an` and "arp who-has"?

Tags: networking, lan, ipv6, arp

In the IPv4 world, when you want to talk to another computer, you ask which MAC address claims a given IPv4 address, the `arp who-has ... tell ...` exchange as per `tcpdump`, and a cache of such mappings from IPv4 to MAC addresses is usually available through [`arp -an`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/arp.8.html).

What about IPv6 with manual configuration? IPv6 addresses don't show up on `arp -an`.

How does one computer discover another one over IPv6 within the same prefix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neighbor Discovery Protocol (NDP) is the IPv6 equivalent of the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP), and on the Unix flavors I'm most familiar with (mostly BSDs) the `ndp(8)` command is the IPv6 equivalent of the `arp(8)` command.

The command-line options for `ndp` are often the same as for `arp`, so `ndp -an` does exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: And `ip -6 neigh` under Linux. See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/374440/ndp-entries-on-linux)

Answer (score 18):

```
ip -6 neigh show
```

Above command is to check arp table for ipv6

Answer (score 0):

On Windows the equivalent command is

> netsh interface ipv6 show neighbors

or in Powershell

> [Get-NetNeighbour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netneighbor?view=windowsserver2022-ps)