# is there table like Ipv4 ARP for IPv6 in linux? where can i (path) find it?

Tags: linux, ipv6, arp, ndp

where can i find NDP table in linux?

1. I'm trying to list the neigbours for the ipv6 address for my appliaction.
2. ip neigh is the command which we use to show the neigh ip address (both ipv4 and ipv6)but i dont want use the system command.
3. where ARP table for ipv6 also known as NDP

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/621593/whats-ipv6-analogue-for-ipv4-arp-an-and-arp-who-has

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the neighbour cache is available via **netlink** (specifically NETLINK_ROUTE), as is nearly all network configuration.

To get all neighbour records, send a Netlink message `nlmsg_type=RTM_GETNEIGH` to the kernel; see the iproute2 (`ip neigh`) source code for more information. You'll probably want to use a library for netlink communications, as the raw structures are a bit cumbersome.

If you're writing Python, [pyroute2](https://pypi.org/project/pyroute2/) can help.

There is no corresponding /proc file for this. (The ones that *do* exist in /proc are basically leftovers from previous era – new ones aren't being added.)